# haproxy status reporting

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, network-monitoring

I've just started using haproxy, so excuse me if I sound silly. `haproxy`  itsekf is working fine and this is the config file that's in use:

```
# This file managed by Puppet
global
  chroot  /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon
  group  haproxy
  log  10.0.2.15 local0
  maxconn  4000
  pidfile  /var/run/haproxy.pid
  stats  socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
  user  haproxy

defaults
  log  global
  maxconn  8000
  option  redispatch
  retries  3
  stats  enable
  timeout  http-request 10s
  timeout  queue 1m
  timeout  connect 10s
  timeout  client 1m
  timeout  server 1m
  timeout  check 10s

listen nlb01 192.168.2.7:80
  balance roundrobin
  mode    http
  option  tcplog
  option  ssl-hello-chk
  option  httpclose
  option  forwardfor
  option  httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
  server  apps01-uk-local 192.168.2.4:8080 check    
  server  apps02-uk-local 192.168.2.5:8080 check
```

In the web-gui, the status is always 'DOWN' even though nodes are running. Tried to search the forum and various other places in the web without having much of luck. Any idea what am I missing here? Thanks in advance for your help. Cheers!!

Comment: What do you have in the LastChk column for the DOWN servers?

Comment: @longneck: `L7STS/404 in 1ms` and `L7STS/404 in 1ms`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LastChk` column tells you what happened the last time haproxy tried to check the status of your server. In your case, the status of `L7STS/404` means that the server returned a 404 error when attempting the check. Your configuration file says to look for `check.txt`. Does that file actually exist? If not, create it and problem solved!